# How to bind a series of commands to a custom hotkey (scripted macro)?

Tags: python, scripting, customization

How would I go about creating a hotkey that would operate as follows?:

1. With an object selected in the modeling viewport:
2. Press Shift + D (this would be the custom shortcut to trigger what follows ,not the default 'duplicate' command)
3. Selected Object gets a catmull-clark subdiv modifier added with default settings `bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')`
4. Subdivision modifier gets applied to mesh (`bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Subdivision")`

?

I am new to Blender as of 2.8 and am interested in customizing the UI to make it more like the software packages I am coming from (Maya and Modo). At the moment I am interested in understanding how to consolidate multiple commands into a single operation that can be bound to a hotkey. I figured this would be a simple enough one to start with. I have some limited python experience from Maya and have been looking at the API but I have been having difficulty understanding how it all works. I understand I would likely need a hotkey .py file to bind the operation to a key and an operator .py file to define the operations and possibly to include the commands. How would I get this working?

I tried a hotkey file in startup that looked like this:

```
import bpy
import os

    km = kc.keymaps.new('Window', space_type='EMPTY',     region_type='WINDOW', modal=False)
    Global_Keys()

    kmi = km.keymap_items.new('mesh.testSubdivide', 'D', 'PRESS', shift=True)
```

With an operator .py file that looked like this:

```
class testSubdivide(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.testSubdivide"
    bl_label = "testSubdivide"        
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'} 

def execute(self, context):
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Subdivision")
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

I know this is wrong...but i'm blocked. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create a quick addon for those kinds of macro (not sure if there is another way).

When you have the script you need to **install it**, **activate** and **save preference** so when you quit blender it doesn't disappear.

[image]

Once you have the script installed you can take the `bl_idname` and use that when you create a shortcut.
In the case of the script that I am sharing the `bl_idname` is `object.simple_macro`

Then in the **Input** tab you can create a new shortcut.

[image]
[image]

if you want to use an existing key binding you probably should disable them before.

[image]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Macro",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "",
}

import bpy


def main(context):
    """Your code here."""

    if bpy.context.selected_objects:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subdivision"].levels = 2
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Subdivision")
        bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()

    else:
        print('no object selected')


class SimpleMacro(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_macro"
    bl_label = "Simple Macro"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleMacro)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleMacro)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_macro()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough and complete explanation! This is exactly the info I was looking for including the steps on how to add the scripts. Big thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to apply a subsurface modifier you can just press CTRL+2..., where the number (2 in this case) is the number of subdivisions you see in the viewport.
If not, i always prefer AutoHotkey (https://www.autohotkey.com/) to bind keystroke sequences to a custom hotkey, it's very easy to program and you can turn it off insantly...

Comment: Thanks for the info! I should have made it clear that I'm more interested in learning how to customize the UI with python in order to recreate a lot of the ease-of-use features of modo that I am used to in order to streamline modeling. Bender absolutely seems to have all the functionality that I need - but often requires multiple time-consuming steps that could be simplified with hotkeys if I could understand how to customize the configuration.